# list of a model with special condition

Tags: python, django-models, django-orm

I have three models

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.charField()

class Base(models.Model):
    serialNum = models.CharFields()
    is_active = models.BooleanFields()

class User_Base(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_base', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    base = models.ForeignKey(Base, related_name='user_base', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

I'm looking for a list of bases, that ***base.is_active=True*** and there are not exist in **User_Base** table, and if some bases are in **User_Base**, their ***status=False***.

How can I define my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
list = Base.objects.filter((Q(user_base__isnull = True) | Q(user_base__isnull = False, user_base__status = False)),
                               is_active = True
                               )
```